# Xcode 8 won't let me edit dynamic prototype cells?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, xcode8

I have only recently updated to Xcode 8. I am creating an app that requires the use of multiple different suitable view cells, however after creating the second cell, I am unable to edit the bottom half of any other cells I create?

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate *UITableViewCell* file with NIB (xib files). Design xib files to whatever you want and after that just register cells to tableview and here we go...

[Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40272757/1575353) which shows how to register custom table view cells.