# Cell from Xib with Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview, xib

I already read and saw some videos about this subject but i can't get this to work. Im trying to a cell from a xib instead of the storyboard.

This is my ViewController (where i have the Table View).

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CellTableView

        cell.test.text = "A";

        return cell;

    }

}
```

This is my CellTableView (the class where i have my Cell):

```
import UIKit

class CellTableView: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    @IBOutlet var teste: UILabel!

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

I always used the Table View Cell inside the Table View on the StoryBoard but i want to try a XIB approach now.

I added the **cell** Identifier on the cell XIB to call it with the dequeueReusableCell method.

What i could be doing wrong? I tried to Outlet the **dataSource** and the **delegate** of the Table View but i got an error (and i think its not the right steps).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to register your nib object.

In `viewDidLoad()`:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "nameOfYourNibFile", bundle: nil)

tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "yourIdentifier")
```

You also need to return the number of sections:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Comment: You mean the Cell identifier, right?

So in the ViewController i just have to put:

let nib = UINib(nibName: "cell", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

? It didnt work. My cells are still empty.

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant the name of your nib file. Should be probably "CellTableView" in your case ...

Comment: That's a straight answer. I'm my case, my tableview uses 3 types of cells: cType1, cType2, cType3. Is there any way to register those custom cells and reuse them with the same identifier? Or maybe should I register them with 3 different identifiers and then check each row and so reuse the matching cellId?

Comment: I was using `tableView.register(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)`, but never got it to work and it was driving me crazy. Registering the nib did the trick.

Comment: @Koen yeap, you're right. There is another trick, when I create my custom `UITableViewCell`,`UICollectionViewCell` fully programmatically, there is no need to identify nib, just writing custom class then its self parameter.  It was a regular habit for me, to me I did not realized that when you use Xib file, Xcode must recognize the Xib file's name but not only custom class name.

Answer (score 2):

> First of all, You have to register your nib object.

```
yourTable?.register(UINib(nibName: "yourCustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
```